# An interesting issue about mysql_real_escpae_string

Tags: php

I have simple form for editting site content:
- a text input for title
- a textarea for content

When adding content, there is no problem, allthings add normally:

```
$chead      = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['chead']));
$ctext      = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['ctext']));
```

But when edittig the article that containig the

```
$chead = 'sdsfsf' "sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg
```

The $chead = 'sdsfsf' 
and the `"sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg` will be lost!!!
What is the problem with `mysql_real_escpae_string`?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get it. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: Most likely a HTML-issue, did you check the _source_ of the page (not the actual output in your browsers. mysql_real_escape_string() has no trouble (with this..) unless your PHP installation is seriously broken, and I highly doubt that.

Comment: ofcourse:
when I add the article, the article title (<text type="text">) is 'sdsfsf' "sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg. When I edit this, It change to 'sdsfsf' and "sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg is lost.
@Wrikken , I have checked the html, "sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg is lost :(

Comment: Where is it lost?  When it gets inserted in the db?  Or via a `var_dump($ctext)`?

Comment: phpExe: did you enable `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)`? Most likely the fault lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Wrikken, error_reporting is on: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Helsinki' for 'EEST/3.0/DST' instead I have printed query and there is no any problem with mysql: [title] => 'sdsfsf' "sdgsdgs"ggdsfsdg

Comment: So, no problem with mysql, then it's the code that makes your html form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track down where the information is getting lost, which isn't likely to be `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Check the `$chead` value that's being generated (before you accuse a particular function of having damaged your data, make sure it is). Then check SQL command you're generating and make sure it's working. Check the database after you insert/update the record and the values returned from the database when you ask for the article back.

In my experience it's much more likely to be a programmer error in the database interaction, or HTML generation that's causing trouble than PHP.  If you really do track the problem down to `mysql_real_escape_string`, you'll probably need to reinstall PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I have solved this proble with adding htmlspecialchars when print input. But yet I cant understand why this problem is happen.